# Is a short circutied battery (I believe) worth anything?

Tags: batteries, 12v, short-circuit

While trying to install 2 Duracell Ultra 12V 46Ah AGM batteries to power a trolling motor in a boat, I accidentally connected my wrench from the positive of one battery to the negative of the other. Obviously, the wrench was metal and got very hot. I, almost instantly, pulled the wrench off the connection. Are these batteries shorted and worth any money? We tried to return them, but the store would not take them. If they are worth any money, how much? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Don’t they work anymore?

Comment: I don't think anything bad have even happened to the battery.

Comment: Just connecting a wrench between two batteries does not short them if the other terminals are not connected. But it seems they were connected because the wrench completed the circuit. You did not mention what else was connected to the batteries and how. Please add this info. Preferably draw a diagram with batteries and wrench and the other stufg.

Comment: if the wrench has weld marks, there’s a good chance one of the 1.5 V cells may have shorted

Comment: If they are dead, they may have some salvage value or some value in the return of your disposal deposit or avoiding a penalty for improper disposal. The value of anything depends on where you live and you have neglected to mention even the continent.

Comment: The batteries were both plugged into the wires for the trolling motor when the wrench connected them. One side of the wrench had a minor weld/burn mark, since the did get so hot so far.

Comment: I recommend to rephrase the question. In terms of EE it is more interesting if the batteries have suffered any damage. wether they have some remaining commercial value depends on how (truthfully) you sell them :)

Answer (score 1):

If the batteries were only shorted for a few seconds, they are probably not damaged.

Just charge them normally, and see how they work.  If they are damaged, they may not take a charge, or may not provide the expected run time for your trolling motor.

Comment: We later found out that they were not the proper batteries to run the trolling motor, thus did not try them. If they do take a charge, then I assume the batteries are fine and we just ran the juice out? Thanks.